# What will be the RegEx for not having 0 at first place after S$

Tags: ios, regex, validation

Right now my RegEx is

```
@"(?!S$0{1})[0-9S$]{5,8}"
```

Please tell the modified version . I have tried everything but couldn't get it right .

I want to allow

```
S$100000
S$1212121
```

Not Allow

```
S$000000
S$000
```

Comment: The regex makes little sense. Please provide more details what it should match, and provide some sample strings to test against.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes not working ..

Comment: @stribizhev Edited the post .

Comment: Like [`^(?!S\\$0)[0-9S$]{5,8}`](https://regex101.com/r/gR8qZ6/1)?

Comment: @stribizhev not working .

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Could you please precise? And if you post the code, it will help understand what you are actually doing. What are the exact criteria for the valid strings? 5 to 8 digits only, not considering `S` and `$`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^S\$0*[1-9]\d*
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/fN0bS4/1)